# How to get nearest row in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table with price column. Now I want to get the nearest row by price.
Like: If I give value 1000 need to return 3,5,6 no. row., if I give value 100 need to return 1,2 no. row

Pack Table Demo

```
id - name - provider_id - price - others_field
1  - name -    1        -  10
2  - name -    1        -  120
3  - name -    1        -  600
4  - name -    1        -  320
5  - name -    1        -  1000
6  - name -    1        -  1020
```

I've tried with the following way by searching google. But it's not working properly.

```
$suggestions = new Pack; 
$suggestions = $suggestions->where('status', 1);   
$suggestions = $suggestions->where('provider_id', $request->provider_id);  
$suggestions = $suggestions->select('*', DB::raw("ABS(price - $request->price) AS distance"))->orderBy('distance'); 

$suggestions = $suggestions->take(3); 
$suggestions = $suggestions->get();  

$curent = '';
$suggestion_lower = '';
$suggestion_higher = '';

foreach ($suggestions as $value) {
    if ( $request->price == $value->price ) {
        $curent = $value;
    }

    if ( $request->price > $value->price ) {
        $suggestion_lower = $value;
    }

    if ( $request->price < $value->price ) {
        $suggestion_higher = $value;
    }
}

$suggestions = [
    'curent' => $curent,
    'suggestion_higher' => $suggestion_higher,
    'suggestion_lower' => $suggestion_lower,
];
```

Comment: you want to fetch nearest 3 records?

Comment: Yes, by price value.

Comment: your query seems okay, whats the problem?

Comment: If I give 1000 as the value it returns Id no. 1 row but it should no. 6 row. as nearest

Comment: you already have the required 3 records, why use foreach loop again? just ignore.

Comment: OK. I'll remove. But data not returning as nearest. when I give value big value like 1000

Comment: I'm really sorry the problem in my foreach loop

Comment: great, atleast you have found your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Get the largest price similar to $price:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE val <= $price ORDER BY val DESC LIMIT 3
```

Get the smallest price similar to $val:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE val >= $price ORDER BY val LIMIT 3
```

Get the closest price similar to $price in either direction:

```
SELECT * FROM tab ORDER BY abs(val - $val) LIMIT 3
```

Comment: In your third solution closest data not working If I give 1000 as the value it returns Id no. 1 row but it should no. 6 row. as nearest

Comment: I want to do it with one query.

Comment: ( SELECT * FROM tab WHERE val >= $price AND val <= $price ORDER BY val LIMIT 3 ) try this

Comment: I'm really sorry the problem in my foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. You will get near 5 records from database

```
SELECT * 
FROM
( ( SELECT *
    FROM pack
    WHERE price <= 1000
    ORDER BY price DESC
      LIMIT 3
  ) 
  UNION ALL
  ( SELECT *
    FROM pack
    WHERE price > 1000 
    ORDER BY price ASC
      LIMIT 3
  ) 
) AS tmp
ORDER BY price
LIMIT 5 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the resulting query for your code, and paste it here?

I suspect the problem is in this line

```
$suggestions = $suggestions->select('*', DB::raw("ABS(price - $request->price) AS distance"))->orderBy('distance');
```

where `$request->price` is treated as string not replaced with the value you expect.